# Should I replace my main water valve with a SharkBite shut off valve?

Tags: plumbing, leak, valve, soldering

Currently my main water shut off valve is soldered using a 3/4 globe valve. However the stem is leaky and I am thinking of replacing it.

Is it a good idea to cut it out and replace it using a SharkBite ball valve? Are SharkBite valves good to use for a main shut off valve replacement in a house or will the pressure deteriorate its O-ring much too quickly? I do not want to solder a joint on as I am a newbie.

Comment: If the Sharkbite parts are okay for the shutoff valves under you sink or behind your toilet, or for connecting the water supply inside your wall to your tub, shower or washing machine valves, I don't know why it wouldn't be okay for your main shutoff value. ;-)

Comment: To amplify @Craig's point:  A main valve gets less use (turned on/off) than any other valve.  My impression is that the forces applied to the joint of a sharkbite valve is what is likely to make it fail, not pressure, flow rate, temperature or any other factor.

Comment: Plan ahead for needing to get the water to your house shut off; a decided nusiance of main water valve replacement if you need someone else (the city water department, say) to shut off the water before it gets to your house.

Comment: @Ecnerwal True that. To me, growing up, shutting off the main water valve meant going out to the front property line with a crescent wrench, taking off the round steel city water meter cover and reaching a couple of feet in there where I couldn't see, usually in water since the city's valve leaked when it was only half open. Guess how fun *that* was in January.  ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, I've considered simply shutting off the existing main valve, splicing in a new quarter-turn lever valve above it, then opening the old valve and never touching it again. It _oughf_ to meet code....

Answer (score 1):

Why not just repack the valve stem?  It's cheaper, easier, and faster.

PS: I am sure the sharkbite valve would be fine.

Comment: ...and repacking does not involve any soldering.

Comment: If I was to repack the stem could I do it under a pressurized situation or do I still have to call the city to shut off the water. I wanted to get a new valve in because I will be paying roughly $300 to shut off and on the water so might as well get a new more reliable valve in there, the existing one is 18 yrs old.

Comment: No, you need to have the water shut off or it will be spraying out the valve stem.

Comment: Buy a curb key as low as 10 from Walmart diy .Yeah you're not supposed to but you aren't supposed to speed

Answer (score 0):

Shark bite valve will be fine. Just make sure you clean the copper pipe thoroughly so there are no rough edges or bits of solder left. 
Have you tried tightening the valve stem on your existing valve? Often this is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The city where I live just changed out the water meters so they can get the readings remotely.  They used all shark bite connectors, so they must work.

Answer (score 0):

Shark bite fittings work great when the pipes are properly seated in fitting. They have a 200 psi air/water rating on them and a 25 year warranty, and can be used above/underground. If used underground they must be wrapped with their silicone tape to protect the brass to preserve the warranty.